# Type in list comprehension send 'None'

Tags: python

Can somebody explain why list is supposed to allow mix types but the following code does not work please (the only difference is the type declaration around the `i`?

The error:

```
print(','.join([buzzfizz(n) for n in range(1,51)]))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

DO NOT WORK:

```
def buzzfizz(i):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            return 'buzz'
        if i % 3 == 0:
            return 'fizz'
        if (i % 3 == 0 & i % 2 == 0):
            return 'buzzfizz'
        else:
            return i

print(','.join([buzzfizz(n) for n in range(1,51)]))
```

WORK:

```
def buzzfizz(i):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            return 'buzz'
        if i % 3 == 0:
            return 'fizz'
        if (i % 3 == 0 & i % 2 == 0):
            return 'buzzfizz'
        else:
            return str(i)

print(','.join([buzzfizz(n) for n in range(1,51)]))
```

Comment: Sure, list is supposed to have mixed types, but you are trying to create a string using `join` on list comprehension which expects all to be a str type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `','.join()` need a list whose elements is `str` type. In your first code, the last `return i` is not a `str` type.

Comment: I see, so basically the list accept mix types but then come the .join which request only str, correct?